# log-normal distribution and standard normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, logarithms, normal-distribution

Why is $(\log X - \mu)/σ \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$ if $\log X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, σ^2)$?

Comment: I´ve edited your question. Check if it was in your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Since if $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $\frac{Z - \mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0, 1)$, simply substitute $Z = \log X$ for the expression to hold.